# Ajax.BeginForm() Ajax Option Not Work in Razor View

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, razor, model-view-controller

**Hi friend AjaxOption Not working in my Razor View**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("TestAvanceSearchRequisition", "Requisition", 
    new AjaxOptions 
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        Confirm = "Do u Want to save",
        UpdateTargetId = "divResponse"   
    }))
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="lebelTD">
                Date From:
            </td>
            <td class="fieldTD">
                @Html.TextBox("requisition_from", "", 
                    new 
                    { 
                        @class = "InputText", 
                        onclick = "javascript:NewCssCal ('requisition_from','ddMMMyyyy','arrow','','','','')", 
                        @style = "border-left:2px solid #FF3C3C;" 
                    })
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="lebelTD">
                Date To:
            </td>
            <td class="fieldTD">
                @Html.TextBox("requisition_end_date", "", 
                    new 
                    { 
                        @class = "InputText", 
                        onclick = "javascript:NewCssCal ('requisition_end_date','ddMMMyyyy','arrow','','','','')", 
                        @style = "border-left:2px solid #FF3C3C;" 
                    })
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">
                <input type="submit" class="smallbtn" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="divResponse">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="lebelTD">Sales Total Amount</td>
                <td class="fieldTD">
                    @Html.TextBox("Salesamt", @TempData["TotalSalesAmout"], new { @class = "InputText" })                                        
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
}
```

Not any Ajax Option not working. Like confirm box, Update Traget Id.
. I had add all reference of Ajax.
Why not Ajax Option Not working. On button click go to Post method and get the result but no confirm box work and load full form.

Comment: You did'nt subscribe the events of form.

Comment: Please show us your `Controller` action method for this form.